# Pattern to let client selectively handle errors in Java

Tags: java, exception

I am writing a wrapper around the DefaultHttpClient to handle some of the error-prone configuration options.
For example I will pre-configure everything to handle UTF-8 properly and to shutdown the connection cleanly.

When a non-200 is returned, I thought about the client registering a handler for a specific status code and then calling it.

I would provide some default handlers to take care of simple cases.

Is this a good pattern for a clean API? If I throw exceptions, the client has to handle cases which might not happen at all as I would have to throw an exception per possible HTTP status code (or most).

The thing I like about handlers is that I can provide a couple of 'default handlers' which might be overwritten...

I'd like to hear your input and maybe get some more creative ideas.

Cheers

Comment: You should accept some answers.

Comment: I think I'll try to accomodate both answers. I'll probably use Checked exceptions for serious errors such as a 500 and add some further unchecked exceptions for 404, 400 and 406.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't create a different exception for each http error code.  At most create one or two general exceptions and store the exact error code as part of the exception.  That way if the client code just wants to log or ignore them it can, or it can get more details based on the error code.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, accepted practice for Java APIs is to employ unchecked exceptions, so client won't need to change it's internal code just to accommodate API's exceptions into client's codebase.

Instead, if you use unchecked exceptions, you'll save your code unchanged except the places where you really need to handle exceptions.

Here're slides about Robert Martin's "Clean code" book which talk about error handling best practices: [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/hebel/clean-code).